# How to check before/after properties for sub group of item in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

working with SharePoint, on the info path form I have a group, which then has a sub group. There can then be any amount of attachment controls on this sub group.

When the form is submitted I am sending the attachments to be uploaded somewhere else. Issue is, when I submit the form, these attachments get sent every time regardless if they are new are not. I currently have the code to handle the uploads in the `ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)` method. I've done some reading and I know I will have to change it so that I am making this call from the `ItemUpdating` method instead. But from there I am unsure what is the best way to check for only 'new' attachments to be sent.

Any suggestions? New to SharePoint development so I can try and clarify if some things don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In general you will always receive all attachments within the EventReceiver. Now you have to check in your EventReceivers ItemUpdating Event which items are new. You have to check the AfterProperties (which you are sending by your form) and the properties.ListItem ([BeforeProperties and AfterProperties in Sharepoint Event Receivers](http://srisharepointdevelopment.blogspot.de/2013/06/beforeproperties-and-afterproperties-in.html)).

First i would load all attachment from the form (AfterProperties) to a collection and then the attachment from the item which already exist in the list which you are trying to update. These attachment of the currently existing item you also load to a collection. Then you can check through LINQ for example if the attachments from you form exist in the item or which do not and then add only the new ones!